Prevent push upgrades (auto and manual) entirely for versions lower than Y.0
I have seen this question, but it only prevents pushing orgs to the newer version from packaging org.
I am interested in solution (if exists) that prevents the user entirely from upgrading from version <= X.X to version Y.0.
Scenario:
We are creating version Y.0, we want it to be installed only on the orgs that do not have our package. We want to prevent upgrading older versions to it both from packaging org (achievable), from app exchange listing and from direct installation url.
InstallHandler (as post install script) won't help, because it executes only after successful upgrade.
Is there any way to achieve this? Maybe I'm missing something?

From who should this be prevented?

General user, I want Y.0 to be installed only on clean orgs without our package.


2GP package (Preferred approach)

In case of 2GP packages, we can specify package upgrade ancestry as stated in this article.
For example, let's say you want to prevent upgrades from version 1.4 to 2.0
You could specify them in the ancestry path like 1.0 -> 1.1 -> 1.2 -> 1.3 -> 2.0
whereas for 1.4 the ancestry path needs to be like 1.1 -> 1.2 -> 1.4

1GP package(Not possible directly IMO, hacky way)

This hack is inspired from the question mentioned here.
In case of 1GP packages, you would need to add a public class & a dummy VF page which depends on it in version X.X+1. Have the customers upgrade to it.
In the Y.0 version, delete this public class & document the error in your product's help page.
I would recommend to convert 1GP into 2GP package since this use case is specifically addressed there.

2nd generation approach won't do any good. I want 2.0 to have no ancestors, it should only be installed on the clean orgs without our package. So ancestry path won't help here.

The second approach sounds interesting, will try it, thank you!

For 2GP,I guess you could specify upgrade path as 1.0 -> Y.0. Assuming none of the customers are using 1.0 (the earliest version), it is essentially like not having an ancestor. Just thinking out loud.

Sounds reasonable, will try it!
